# How can I modify attributes of an HTML element with chromedp

Tags: go, dom, chromedp

I'm trying to set the disabled attribute of an input element to false with chromedp. I can modify it's value with the console chrome dev tool but didn't achieved it in my code.

I will explain the complete behaviour of this input and why I need it.

1. I have a first select input that I modify with this command

   ```golang
   err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SetValue("select[name=lstDoc]",
       rcp, chromedp.ByQuery))
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   ```

   Normally you must click it and it automatically change the disabled attributes of the one I'm targeting when you modify it's value. It's working.
2. Now we arrive at element I can't modify, I can put date in it, so I now my selector is correct put I can't change the disabled attribute, here what I'm actually trying:

   ```golang
   dateDebut := "#txtDebutMAJ"
   err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SetAttributeValue(dateDebut,
       "disabled", "false", chromedp.ByQuery))
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   ```

I have run chromedp with `headless` at false so i can clearly see that the element is still disabled because it's always grayed out.

What I have tried with the console and it worked:

```js
$("#txtDebutMAJ").disabled = false
```

Comment: I have zero experience with chromedp, but judging form the docs, shouldn't it be something like `chromedp.SetAttributeValue("select[name=lstDoc]#txtDebutMAJ", ...)`? That is, the selector expession should match both the node (the element) _and_ the attribute on it.

Comment: maybe it's not clear in my question but `select[name=lstDoc]` and `#txtDebutMAJ` are two different element, the first one is a select and the second one is an input where you can put some text

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find a solution and use less code, the origin of the problem is the following, the click on a select don't trigger is `onchange` attribute so i used the `SendKeys` function instead.

There is a post about this issue here : https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/607

and the solution I have used is here : https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/8#issuecomment-602279477

For conclusion i was using this code to set the value of the select :

```
    err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SetValue("select[name=lstDoc]", rcp, chromedp.ByQuery))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
```

and this for setting the value of the attribute :

```
err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SetAttributeValue(dateDebut, "disabled", "false", chromedp.ByQuery))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

For finnally only using this piece of code :

```
err = chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SendKeys(selectRCP, "RCP"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

work like a charm !